# Is it possible to check in Laravel controller who requests the page?

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller I have a function `welcome` that can be called by unauthenticated users and the administrator.

In my `welcome` view I use `@auth` and `@guest` to determine what content to display

```
public function welcome() {
  // these are for users and admin
  $header = Data::where("section", "header")->get();
  $header_secondary = Data::where("section", "header_secondary")->get();
  $tel = Data::where("section", "tel")->get();
  $working_hours = Data::where("section", "working_hours")->get();
  // this data is for admins only.. Is there a way not to include it in
  // the view, if the request is done by a regular user?
  $important_data = Important::where("year", "2017")->get()
  return view("welcome", compact("header", "header_secondary", 
  "tel", "working_hours", "important_data"));
}
```

But can I reorganize my `welcome` function in such a way that if a regular user makes a request it would not send him a view with data intended for admin?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#protecting-routes Check out the `Auth` facade specifically the `check`  method and etc.

Comment: @bassxzero thank you, I missed this when reading the documentation